# Intermittent Demand Forecasting for highly seasonal items

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality, intermittent-time-series

I have a dataset with intermittent sales and very high seasonality and I want to forecast that but it is my understanding that Croston's method only works on non seasonal items. Is there any other method for forecasting those items?